# button to switch i18n language

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, i18next

my code is in react and uses the i18next library. this was previously done with material ui's `Select` API, where i was able to switch languages using the `value`, `onChange`, and `inputProps` parameters. however, the design has since changed to be two separate buttons (eg. 'en' and 'zh') instead of the switch. this is the code that successfully toggles between two languages with the `Select` API (language toggling = dropdown menu):

```
const LanguageMenu = () => {
    const { t, i18n } = useTranslation()
    const classes = useStyles()

    const [values, setValues] = useState({
        language: i18next.language
    })

    function handleChange(event) {
        i18n.changeLanguage(event.target.value)

        setValues(oldValues => ({
            ...oldValues,
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
        }))
    }

    return(
        <>
            <Select
    value={values.language}
    onChange={(event) => handleChange(event)}
    disableUnderline
    inputProps={{
        name: 'language'
    }}
    classes={{
        select: classes.selectFocus
    }}
>
        

<MenuItem value={'en'}><p role="img" aria-label="en"></p></MenuItem>
<MenuItem value={'zh-Hant'}><p role="img" aria-label="zh"></p></MenuItem>
</Select>
        </>
    )
}
```

I've looked at the `ButtonGroup` API and the `Button` API and none of them seem to give me the parameters the `Select` API offers. I'm looking into using the native `button` in HTML, but i still need to pass in the `values.language` context before calling `value={'en'}` and `value={'zh-Hant'}` and i'm not sure how i can achieve that. i've also tried the code below, which doesn't work:

```
<button onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}>En</button>
<button onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}>Zh</button>
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give your button some attributes and you can access them with the help of those attributes.

Something like

```
<button id="EN" value="EN" name="EN" onChange={(event) => handleChange(event)}>En</button>
<button id="ZH" value="ZH" name="ZH" onChange={(event) => handleChange(event)}>Zh</button>
```

In you handleChange funtion you can get element through ID.

```
function handleChange(e:any){
    var x = document.getElementById(e.target.id).value;
    //Use x in your code as per requirement

// x will have the value of your button you canget whatever you want value,name etc
}
```

I also had example for you created you can check for reference.

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GRZ6X9IAGG39

I hope this will solve your problem. Let me know if it works.

Comment: thanks for answering! the example works great, but the code you suggested doesn't work for my project. i'm not sure if the i18next language is rendered as a DOM element, because `myFunction` wasn't called

Comment: @cookiestarninja Well i18next works with the tags that needs to change or rendered as per language specific what you can do is just call the method to change or trigger langauge change i.e i18n.changeLanugae('<pass the language>'). Try it and it will work.

Comment: omg i should've just went with i18n.changeLanguage lol. this worked, thanks!